# Rotation matrix with limited rotation speed

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, rotations

I'm working on a flight-simulator type program, and I'm attempting to make elements (e.g. missiles) that lock-onto and track a target. There are plenty of rotation matrix implementations online that deal with rotating a vector to face another vector. Here's the one I've been using from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula#Matrix_notation):
$$\mathbf R = \mathbf I + (\sin\theta)\mathbf {\hat K} + (1-\cos\theta)\mathbf {\hat K}^2$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors and $\mathbf {\hat K}$ is the cross product matrix built from the unit vector $\mathbf {\hat k}$ around which to rotate:
$$\mathbf {\hat K} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & -k_z & k_y \\ k_z & 0 & -k_x \\ -k_y & k_x & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
Since I compute $\mathbf k$ using the cross product of my target current heading $\mathbf {\hat v}$ and the target vector $\mathbf {\hat t}$, it's length is already equal to $\sin\theta$. Computing the cross product matrix from before without normalizing $\mathbf k$ gives: $\mathbf K = (\sin\theta)\mathbf {\hat K}$. This simplifies the first formula to:
$$\mathbf R = \mathbf I + \mathbf K + \mathbf K^2/(1+\cos\theta)$$
This formula works great in addition to being ridiculously sexy.

Now, here's my issue:

The formulas above work fantastically, but they "yank" the trackers around instantly, which is a little jarring, and not particularly realistic in a flight-sim. To combat this I'm attempting to set a limit on the rotation speed. I currently find $\sin$ and $\cos$ using:
$$\sin\theta = \vert \mathbf {\hat v} \times \mathbf {\hat t} \vert$$
$$\cos\theta = \vert \mathbf {\hat v} \cdot \mathbf {\hat t} \vert$$
Then I check to see if $\cos\theta > \cos\theta_{max}$ and if it is, I have to recompute $\cos\theta = \cos\theta_{max}$ as well as $\sin\theta = \sin\theta_{max}$. Additionally, I then have to normalize $\mathbf k$ and use the first rotation equation. It works, but it's certainly not as elegant as the simplified equation.

My question is this:

Am I missing anything that would make this formula simpler (and faster)? Is there an easier way to compute a rotation matrix with a limited rotation speed than this?

Comment: Take a look at "slerps" : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp which can be used with rotations as you do or with quaternions.

Answer (score 1):

For a natural effect, one needs to look at the physics of rotating an object (such as a missile). The rotational inertia law would be $I\ddot{\theta}=\tau$, so the problem of starting from an angle of $0$ to an angle $\theta_0$ is achieved by a quadratic formula $$\theta(t)=\theta_0 f(t),\qquad f(t)=\begin{cases}2t^2 & 0<t<\frac{1}{2} \\ 1-2(1-t)^2& \frac{1}{2}<t<1\end{cases}$$

In practice a similar effect is achieved by $$f(t)=t^2(3-2t).$$ The comment mentions Slerp but that needs to compute three sine values at each step.